# Which astra resists Varunastra?

Tags: weapon

Varunastra is a celestial weapon that unleashes water and is used as an encounter to Agneyastra, which releases fires and flames. My question is, how do you counter Varunastra?

Comment: Vayuvya astra (wind, to blue away the rain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03170.htm here it is mentioned that visoshana is the celestial weapon used to dry water .

"Thereupon, I discharged that celestial weapon which I had learnt from Indra--even the dreadful and flaming Visoshana: and by that the water was dried up."